# Создать слайдер с возможным динамическим добавлением новых слайдов

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Помогите добавить html в приведённый ниже код что бы увидеть его работу.

```js
$('.add-remove').slick({
 slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
 });
 $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
 slideIndex++;
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
 });

 $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
 $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
 if (slideIndex !== 0){
 slideIndex--;
 }
});
```

Comment: Скорее всего html можно найти на том сайте, откуда вы взяли этот код. Угадывать то, что задумывалось разработчиком для этого сдайдера весьма непростая задача. Также  помимо html, надо еще и стили создать.

Comment: Нужен полный код..  наугад писать не очень.

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Офф. ссылка на github с примерами подключения](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)